# How do I style correctly a floating label to not stay on top of input field?

Tags: css, forms, input, label

I am trying to make a floating label input form. I don't know how to name it.

```css
.form input,
label {
  transition: all 500ms;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

.form input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.form label {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translate(1.5em, -2em);
}

.form input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5fa8d3;
}

.form input:focus+label {
  transform: translate(0, -3.4em);
}
```

```html
<form action="get" class="login-form">
  <h1>Log In</h1>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="none" required />
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
</form>
```

I also tried to add `overflow: hidden` on the `.form input:focus + label` but it didn't work, the content of the input is overwritten by the label.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/

Comment: @user3489433 i've tried that but it didn't work for me.. that's why I came here for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `.` mark before `form` in the css, and there is no class by the name of `.form`. If you want to apply it on the `form` element, then use it without the `.` selector.

And to persist the hovered state of labels, it has to be identified that if the `input` elememts are filled of not. We can use javascript and add an attribute `filled=true` to the input element if it is filled and remove when it is empty

```js
document.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName && event.target.nodeName === "INPUT") {
    if (event.target.value) {
      event.target.setAttribute('filled', 'true')
    } else {
      event.target.removeAttribute('filled')

    }
  }
})
```

```css
form input,
label {
  transition: all 500ms;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}

form input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  width: 100%;
}

form label {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: translate(1.5em, -2em);
}

form input:focus {
  border: none;
  outline-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5fa8d3;
}

form input:focus+label {
  transform: translate(0, -3.4em);
}

form input[filled="true"]+label {
  transform: translate(0, -3.4em);
}
```

```html
<form action="get" class="login-form">
  <h1>Log In</h1>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="none" required />
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. i forgot to add into the html code. I have in my original code a div that wraps that form and has the class `.form`.

Comment: In that case, keep the original CSS and just add the `form input[filled="true"]+label` part in it.

Comment: Already did. Adapted a bit to work with my vue component. Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you can use the `:valid` pseudoclass to keep the label afloat after entering data (you can only do this because the fields are marked as 'required' !!)

```css
.login-form input:focus+label
.login-form input:valid+label {
  transform: translate(0, -3.4em);
}
```

(side note: your original code says `.form` but I suppose you mean `.login-form` ?)

If you want to be able to do this for all fields and not only required fields you either have to track the values in it using javascript and set a class accordingly, or use a bit of 'hack' using placeholders:

```html
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder=" " />
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
```

```css
form input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label
form input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) + label {
  transform: translate(0, -3.4em);
}
```

(If you don't need IE support you can leave out the `:-ms-input-placeholder`)